# Get profile URL from LinkedIN API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to retrieve the LinkedIn public URL through the API by letting users login trough the OAUTH V2 endpoint. The r_liteprofile is not providing this.

I see a lot of people using the basic profile (r_basicprofile) scope to get the vanityName, but it seems to be deprecated? Some mentions that you need to be part of the partner program but that seems to be closed as well?

Are there any other way to get the URL to the users profile after they logged in?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `vanityName` of the authenticated user.

To get the vanityName (which is what you need, meaning the linkedin.com/in/**vanity**) you need to query the /me endpoint using the Bearer token in the header of your request.

Last time I checked, you could query that endpoint with the `r_liteprofile` permission.

[Here's a link to the documentation for querying the public profile url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#public-profile-url)